# Query to Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, pubs

I have been trying to learn using the `Pubs` database. I have been trying to figure out how to create a stored procedure to create a profitability column.

The current code I have is this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pub_id, ((price * ytd_sales) - advance / 100 * royalty) as [Profit]
FROM titles
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
```

The two issues I am having are `pub_id` contains duplicates since they're sorted using `title_id` and one publisher can publish more than one book.

I am trying to add all the profits together and only have 1 row per publisher. And I am trying to turn that into a stored procedure.

Comment: can you provide some sample output that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean-

```
SELECT pub_id, sum((price * ytd_sales) - advance / 100 * royalty) as [Profit]
FROM titles
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pud_id
ORDER BY pub_id
```